# cannot select vertex in vert select mode, and i also cannot make any transformations to an edge or face i have selected

Tags: modeling

[image]

so as you can see, ive got this, and im in vert mode, and i cant select any verts. ive restarted blender, my pc. I also cant unwrap it, when i press unwrap, (if if were to have the seams, which i did before) it would simply not make islands for them, and also when i do any edit mode thing, i guess, it deselects the object and nothing happens. like if i do tris to quads, everything deselects and i get no difference, even though i applied a triangulate modifier and had it include the already made quads.

Comment: i forgot to mention this is only  happening on certain objects so is there some sort of mode im in?

Comment: Please share your .blend file so we can check your settings. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/